# Alternatives for Bumblebee?

Tags: linux, nvidia, bumblebee

Last [commit](https://github.com/Bumblebee-Project/Bumblebee/commits/master) to Bumblebee was in 2013 and since then the project appears to be dead. Has an better alternative to Bumblebee (a fork perhaps) emerged? Have NVidia started supporting Optimus for Linux in their newer drivers (if yes, is it stable enough)? And most importantly, is it safe to run Bumblebee given the long inactivity with later drivers or GPUs?

Comment: Bumblebee Project seems active (just for the users who came here recently like I did).

Answer (score 3):

Bumblebee project is not very active by any means, but it is not completely dead. They have switched to `develop` branch instead of `master`, which is why you see the last commit from 2013. The last commit to the `develop` branch is made on January 21st, 2015, and there is also a commit from July 29th, 2015 in the `module-unload` branch.

Bumblebee still works though some issues with the recent Nvidia drivers need to be fixed ([unload `nvidia-uvm` and `nvidia-modeset` modules before unloading the `nvidia` module](https://github.com/Bumblebee-Project/Bumblebee/issues/699))